# How to horizontally align 2 div containing columns of text?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a horizontal scrolling website and I'm trying to align 2 divs with columns of text.

I can't manage to align these 2 divs (the second one is at the bottom left of the first one) and some of the columns are outside the div.

How can I resolve this?

**HTML**:

```html
<body>
<div id="main">
   <div id="content">
      <div id="article"><!-- columns of text --></div>
      <div id="comments"><!-- columns of text --></div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    background: transparent;
}
#main {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#content {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: black;
}
#article {
    border: 10px solid yellow;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-column-width: 300px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
    -moz-column-width: 300px;
    -moz-column-gap: 40px;
    column-width: 300px;
    column-gap: 40px;
    background: green;
}
#comments {
    border: 10px solid red;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-column-width: 300px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
    -moz-column-width: 300px;
    -moz-column-gap: 40px;
    column-width: 300px;
    column-gap: 40px;
    background: blue;
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kz5ch49w/54/

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to another question I answered, except the other person had 3 divs he wanted horizontally aligned.

Your options are:

1. Add this to your css:

   ```css
   #articles,#comments {display: inline-block;}
   ```
2. Change the inner-most divs to spans and add this to your CSS:

   ```css
   #articles, #comments {display: block;}
   ```

Comment: I tried the first option, but it doesn't work in the JSFiddle demo... And for the second option, could you be more explicit ? Are you suggesting me to change all `<p></p>` to `<span></span>` ?

Comment: What would swapping out `div` for `span` achieve, when you then make the spans `block` again? Result would be exactly the same …

Comment: @CBroe It would increase compatibility with older web browsers. According to the website test tool at try.powermapper.com, display:inline-block; is not compatible with older versions of some web browsers.

Comment: How does replacing an element which is `block` by default with another element that you _make_ `block` increase compatibility with browser that have a problem with `inline-block` …?

Comment: Could you please answer the question of my first comment ?

Comment: @Guillaume What I mean is the actual div tags that you want horizontally aligned. That means change the inner most `<div ID="whatever>some text</div>` to `<span ID="whatever">some text</span>` and @CBroe, since he wanted two elements side by side, span would be a better option than div and span is inline by default which is why I recommended making it a block element through CSS.

Comment: If I change div to span, then I must remove all <p>some text</p>, since I can't put an inline element into a block one. Am I wrong ? Like this : http://jsfiddle.net/kz5ch49w/60/ ?

Comment: You can't put a block element inside an inline element, especially when it comes to div and span, at least that's according to the w3c validator.

Comment: I changed `<div id="article></div>` to `<span id="article"></span>` and `<div id="comments></div>` to `<span id="comments"></span>`. So I removed `<p></p>` and I pasted the text into the span, directly (I will have to find a solution concerning the format of my text that would be now lost). Then, I add the `{ display : block }` in my CSS. And I still don't get the point, sorry... http://jsfiddle.net/kz5ch49w/60/

Comment: The use of span increases compatibility in older web browsers in comparison to keeping them as divs and using "display:inline-block;"

Comment: OK, but it solves nothing... I will try to explain my problem in another way. I would like to get exactly this : http://jsfiddle.net/kz5ch49w/62/ But in this demo, widths of `#content`, `#article` and `#content` are defined. My problem is that I can't define `width` in my real project because my content is dynamic. So I have to assign 100% or auto to `width`and my divs aren't aligned anymore...

Answer (score 0):

```
 <body>
 <div id="main">
 <div id="content">
  <div id="article"><!-- columns of text --></div>
  <div id="comments"><!-- columns of text --></div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </body>
```

css:

```
 body { margin:0; padding:0; color:white; background:transparent;width:auto }
 div { position:absolute;margin:1%;}
```

Use absolute position and calculate width and left position serially. So you can use horizontal scrolling. Eg : http://jsfiddle.net/kz5ch49w/57/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I didn't get it... I tried it in the JSFiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/kz5ch49w/56/

Comment: Thank you for the update but I need the columns of text in the divs.

Comment: I can't get what you mean by columns of text.

Comment: In my demo, there are columns and in these columns, there is some text (in my CSS, there are `column-gap`, `column-width` etc...). I need these columns because the content is dynamic and I can't create one div for each column of text : it wouldn't be responsive and it would change for all the pages of my website...

Answer (score 0):

I update your jsfiddle where I changed CSS properties. like position , height , width.

http://jsfiddle.net/kz5ch49w/58/

As your 62 jsfiddle:- I update fiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/kz5ch49w/64/

Check for the responsive by changing browser or fiddle height, width or add or modify content.

what you need to do, never give hardcore height , width. you can give 50% width , float:left for both div when you want horizontally set. or you can set width 33% of 3 div, if you wish to set horizontally. means your div will set in 100% width by-default, you can set float left will set to left and width will use for its content.

As your requirement never use position and -moz... (this is default add by mozila browser), each browser have its own content properties, when we not give anything, every browser add properties itself which same properties may you not get in another browser.

Give always % based height width for responsive, never though about content height, it will automatically scroll down if you give % width or not give the width(in this case it take browser width or parent div width(if you given)).

I think, I explain you better.

Update HTML

```
    <html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            color: white;
            background: transparent;
        }

        #main {
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        #content {
            overflow-x: scroll;
            overflow-y: auto;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background: black;
        }

        #article {
            border: 10px solid yellow;
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            /*height: 100%;
            position: relative;*/
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-size: 25px;
            text-align: left;
            /*-webkit-column-width: 300px;
            -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
            -moz-column-width: 300px;
            -moz-column-gap: 40px;
            column-width: 300px;
            column-gap: 40px;*/
            background: green;
        }

        #comments {
            border: 10px solid red;
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            /*height: 100%;
            position: relative;*/
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-size: 25px;
            text-align: left;
            /*-webkit-column-width: 300px;
            -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
            -moz-column-width: 300px;
            -moz-column-gap: 40px;
            column-width: 300px;
            column-gap: 40px;*/
            background: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>


<body>

    <div id="main">

        <div id="content">

            <div id="article">

                <p>Sed (saepe enim redeo ad Scipionem, cuius omnis sermo erat de amicitia) querebatur, quod omnibus in rebus homines diligentiores essent; capras et oves quot quisque haberet, dicere posse, amicos quot haberet, non posse dicere et in illis quidem parandis adhibere curam, in amicis eligendis neglegentis esse nec habere quasi signa quaedam et notas, quibus eos qui ad amicitias essent idonei, iudicarent. Sunt igitur firmi et stabiles et constantes eligendi; cuius generis est magna penuria. Et iudicare difficile est sane nisi expertum; experiendum autem est in ipsa amicitia. Ita praecurrit amicitia iudicium tollitque experiendi potestatem.</p>

                <p>Equitis Romani autem esse filium criminis loco poni ab accusatoribus neque his iudicantibus oportuit neque defendentibus nobis. Nam quod de pietate dixistis, est quidem ista nostra existimatio, sed iudicium certe parentis; quid nos opinemur, audietis ex iuratis; quid parentes sentiant, lacrimae matris incredibilisque maeror, squalor patris et haec praesens maestitia, quam cernitis, luctusque declarat.</p>

                <p>Et hanc quidem praeter oppida multa duae civitates exornant Seleucia opus Seleuci regis, et Claudiopolis quam deduxit coloniam Claudius Caesar. Isaura enim antehac nimium potens, olim subversa ut rebellatrix interneciva aegre vestigia claritudinis pristinae monstrat admodum pauca.</p>

                <p>Ego vero sic intellego, Patres conscripti, nos hoc tempore in provinciis decernendis perpetuae pacis habere oportere rationem. Nam quis hoc non sentit omnia alia esse nobis vacua ab omni periculo atque etiam suspicione belli?</p>

                <p>Quibus ita sceleste patratis Paulus cruore perfusus reversusque ad principis castra multos coopertos paene catenis adduxit in squalorem deiectos atque maestitiam, quorum adventu intendebantur eculei uncosque parabat carnifex et tormenta. et ex is proscripti sunt plures actique in exilium alii, non nullos gladii consumpsere poenales. nec enim quisquam facile meminit sub Constantio, ubi susurro tenus haec movebantur, quemquam absolutum.</p>

                <p>Sed laeditur hic coetuum magnificus splendor levitate paucorum incondita, ubi nati sunt non reputantium, sed tamquam indulta licentia vitiis ad errores lapsorum ac lasciviam. ut enim Simonides lyricus docet, beate perfecta ratione vieturo ante alia patriam esse convenit gloriosam.</p>

                <p>Exsistit autem hoc loco quaedam quaestio subdifficilis, num quando amici novi, digni amicitia, veteribus sint anteponendi, ut equis vetulis teneros anteponere solemus. Indigna homine dubitatio! Non enim debent esse amicitiarum sicut aliarum rerum satietates; veterrima quaeque, ut ea vina, quae vetustatem ferunt, esse debet suavissima; verumque illud est, quod dicitur, multos modios salis simul edendos esse, ut amicitiae munus expletum sit.</p>

                <p>Figgeri, inquam, Triari, nullo pacto potest, ut non dicas, quid non probes eius, a quo dissentias. quid enim me prohiberet Epicureum esse, si probarem, quae ille diceret? cum praesertim illa perdiscere ludus esset. Quam ob rem dissentientium inter se reprehensiones non sunt vituperandae, maledicta, contumeliae, tum iracundiae, contentiones concertationesque in disputando pertinaces indignae philosophia mihi videri solent.</p>

            </div>

            <div id="comments">

                <p>Sed (saepe enim redeo ad Scipionem, cuius omnis sermo erat de amicitia) querebatur, quod omnibus in rebus homines diligentiores essent; capras et oves quot quisque haberet, dicere posse, amicos quot haberet, non posse dicere et in illis quidem parandis adhibere curam, in amicis eligendis neglegentis esse nec habere quasi signa quaedam et notas, quibus eos qui ad amicitias essent idonei, iudicarent. Sunt igitur firmi et stabiles et constantes eligendi; cuius generis est magna penuria. Et iudicare difficile est sane nisi expertum; experiendum autem est in ipsa amicitia. Ita praecurrit amicitia iudicium tollitque experiendi potestatem.</p>

                <p>Equitis Romani autem esse filium criminis loco poni ab accusatoribus neque his iudicantibus oportuit neque defendentibus nobis. Nam quod de pietate dixistis, est quidem ista nostra existimatio, sed iudicium certe parentis; quid nos opinemur, audietis ex iuratis; quid parentes sentiant, lacrimae matris incredibilisque maeror, squalor patris et haec praesens maestitia, quam cernitis, luctusque declarat.</p>

                <p>Et hanc quidem praeter oppida multa duae civitates exornant Seleucia opus Seleuci regis, et Claudiopolis quam deduxit coloniam Claudius Caesar. Isaura enim antehac nimium potens, olim subversa ut rebellatrix interneciva aegre vestigia claritudinis pristinae monstrat admodum pauca.</p>

                <p>Ego vero sic intellego, Patres conscripti, nos hoc tempore in provinciis decernendis perpetuae pacis habere oportere rationem. Nam quis hoc non sentit omnia alia esse nobis vacua ab omni periculo atque etiam suspicione belli?</p>

                <p>Quibus ita sceleste patratis Paulus cruore perfusus reversusque ad principis castra multos coopertos paene catenis adduxit in squalorem deiectos atque maestitiam, quorum adventu intendebantur eculei uncosque parabat carnifex et tormenta. et ex is proscripti sunt plures actique in exilium alii, non nullos gladii consumpsere poenales. nec enim quisquam facile meminit sub Constantio, ubi susurro tenus haec movebantur, quemquam absolutum.</p>

                <p>Sed laeditur hic coetuum magnificus splendor levitate paucorum incondita, ubi nati sunt non reputantium, sed tamquam indulta licentia vitiis ad errores lapsorum ac lasciviam. ut enim Simonides lyricus docet, beate perfecta ratione vieturo ante alia patriam esse convenit gloriosam.</p>

                <p>Exsistit autem hoc loco quaedam quaestio subdifficilis, num quando amici novi, digni amicitia, veteribus sint anteponendi, ut equis vetulis teneros anteponere solemus. Indigna homine dubitatio! Non enim debent esse amicitiarum sicut aliarum rerum satietates; veterrima quaeque, ut ea vina, quae vetustatem ferunt, esse debet suavissima; verumque illud est, quod dicitur, multos modios salis simul edendos esse, ut amicitiae munus expletum sit.</p>

                <p>Figgeri, inquam, Triari, nullo pacto potest, ut non dicas, quid non probes eius, a quo dissentias. quid enim me prohiberet Epicureum esse, si probarem, quae ille diceret? cum praesertim illa perdiscere ludus esset. Quam ob rem dissentientium inter se reprehensiones non sunt vituperandae, maledicta, contumeliae, tum iracundiae, contentiones concertationesque in disputando pertinaces indignae philosophia mihi videri solent.</p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but then, the scrolling isn't horizontal, and my content isn't in columns anymore...

Comment: It is now responsive ui. what you want means you want to restrict in max-width size, if yes, then just give overflow:auto; width : __%. I break both div in 50% width. if you give 100% it will comes in vertical.

Comment: The problem is that the content of #article and #comments is very very long in my real project and I really need to put the text into columns.

Comment: I want the 2 divs horizontally aligned, but with the text into columns (like in my demo). In my first JSFiddle demo, one is at the bottom of the other. I would like them both horizontally aligned and the content into columns.

Comment: yes, right now the same display as you want. the content within the div and both div is set horizontally with responsive. I update my answer with full html code. check it locally.

Comment: I would like to get exactly this : http://jsfiddle.net/kz5ch49w/62/ But in this demo, widths of `#content`, `#article` and `#main` are defined. My problem is that I can't define `width` in my real project because my content is dynamic. So I have to assign 100% or auto to `width`and my divs aren't aligned anymore...

Comment: I meant "widths of `#content`, `#article` and `#comments` are defined". Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation... But as I mentioned, I'm working on an horizontal scrolling website. Now, in the demo, we have columns, divs horizontally aligned, but vertical scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes to your CSS. This will align the two divs horizontally with respect to each other:

CSS:

```css
#main {
   left: 0;
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
}
#content {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#article {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 green;
    border: 10px solid yellow;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    font-size: 25px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 50%;
}
#comments {
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 blue;
   border: 10px solid red;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   float: left;
   font-size: 25px;
   position: relative;
   text-align: left;
   width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I need the columns properties included in the `#article` and `#comments` divs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It makes each box have equal width (by the 50% width defined in the CSS) and you can change 2000px to whatever screen size you want. I made it 2000px on my test to give me a reason to scroll and because 2000 exceeds my screen width.

```
<html>
<title>x</title>
<head>
<style>
body { margin:0; padding:0; color:white; background:transparent; }
#main {width:2000px;}
#article {border:10px solid yellow; float:left; width:50%; height:100%; box-sizing: border-box; font-size:25px; text-align:left; -webkit-column-width: 300px; -webkit-column-gap: 40px; -moz-column-width: 300px; -moz-column-gap: 40px; column-width: 300px; column-gap: 40px; background:green; }
#comments {border:10px solid red; float:right; width:50%; height:100%; box-sizing: border-box; font-size:25px; text-align:left; -webkit-column-width: 300px; -webkit-column-gap: 40px; -moz-column-width: 300px; -moz-column-gap: 40px; column-width: 300px; column-gap: 40px; background:blue; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="article"><p>dsgkhskgshgk</p><p>dkjghskgdhskgh</p></div>
<div id="comments"><p>dsgkhskgshgk</p><p>dkjghskgdhskgh</p></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```